# If a curve has unit speed, is the magnitude of its tangent and normal vectors equal to $1$?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

If a curve has unit speed, is the magnitude of its tangent and normal vectors equal to $1$?
I am having trouble seeing this.

if r is the curve, then the tangent is $r'$. Also, normal vector is $r''/|r''|$

My professor wrote $K$(curvature) = $|r''| = |-torsion*normal| = |torsion|$.
Where did the normal and the negative go?

$torsion = [(r' x r'') *r''']/|r' x r''|^2$

Comment: That depends on how you compute such vectors. For any unit tangent vector, we could always multiply it by some scalar and get a new vector which is tangent to the curve with a magnitude different from $1$. You need to explain more carefully what you mean by "tangent' and "normal" vector for your question to make sense.

Comment: For instance can you provide the formula you use to compute these vectors?

Comment: if r is the curve, then the tangent is r'. Also, normal vector is r''/|r''|

Comment: That helps. Please edit your question to include those formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed of a curve by definition is $\|\vec{r}'\|$. If you define your "tangent vector" to be $\vec{r}'$ then having unit speed means that this tangent vector has a magnitude equal to $q$.

Your normal vector, because of the way it is defines always has a magnitude equal to $1$. This is because the vector is defined as $\vec{r}''$ divided by its own magnitude. When you divide a vector by it's magnitude the resulting vector has a magnitude equal to $1$.

The norm of a vector times a scalar obeys the following rule $ \| \alpha \vec{v} \| = | \alpha | \| \vec{v} \| $. The torsion that your professor gave is a scalar, so we can apply this rule.

$$\| -torsion * \vec{normal} \| = | -torsion| \| \vec{normal} \| $$
$$ = |-torsion| * 1 $$
$$ = | - torsion | = |torsion| $$

Comment: My professor wrote K(curvature) = |r''| = |-torque*normal| = |torque|. Where did the normal and the negative go?

Comment: Yes I see that you just added that bit. You need to define "torque" now in the question statement.

Comment: torque = [(r' x r'') *r''']/|r' x r''|^2

Comment: Please edit your question to include that formula.

Comment: Are you sure that your professor has the torque defined as a scalar and not a vector?

Comment: i'm so sorry i meant torsion, and yes its a scalar function

Comment: At this point if I have anwered your question it would be appropriate to accept my answer.

Comment: Can we say, ‖−∗‖ = sqrt(torsion^2*normal^2) = |torsion|*sqrt(n*n). Since n is an orthonormal vector then n*n = 1, so we are left with |torsion|

Comment: Yes you can say that.

Comment: More simply, because $n$ is a normalized vector, that means its magnitude, $\|n\|$, is equal to $1$

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :)